# OEM USB driver for Windows XP by Philips: Eclipse wont see the phone

Tags: android, debugging, eclipse-adt, usb-drive

I have smartphone `philips w6610`. And  I want to use my phone for debugging my apps.

I installed standard usb driver from https://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html. Windows  determines the phone just as the data storage.

But Eclipse wont see the phone. I didn't find oem usb driver in the list:
http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html